# How can I select distinct by one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, distinct

I have a table with the columns below, and I need to get the values if COD is duplicated, get the non NULL  on VALUE column. If is not duplicated, it can get a NULL VALUE. Like the example:

I'm using SQL SERVER.

This is what I get:

```
COD ID  VALUE
28  1   NULL
28  2   Supermarket
29  1   NULL
29  2   School
29  3   NULL
30  1   NULL
```

This is what I want:

```
COD ID  VALUE
28  2   Supermarket
29  2   School
30  1   NULL
```

What I'm tryin' to do:

```
;with A as (    
(select DISTINCT COD,ID,VALUE from CodId where ID = 2)  
UNION   
(select DISTINCT COD,ID,NULL from CodId where ID != 2) 
)select * from A order by COD
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (COD INT, ID INT,  VALUE VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @T 

VALUES(28,  1,   NULL),
(28,  2   ,'Supermarket'),
(29,  1   ,NULL),
(29,  2   ,'School'),
(29,  3   ,NULL),
(30,  1   ,NULL)


;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, RN= ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COD ORDER BY VALUE DESC) FROM @T
)
SELECT COD, ID ,VALUE  FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Result:

```
COD         ID          VALUE
----------- ----------- --------------------
28          2           Supermarket
29          2           School
30          1           NULL
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use the `WITH TIES` clause in concert with `Row_Number()`

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties * 
 from  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By [COD] order by Value Desc)
```

**Returns**

```
COD ID  VALUE
28  2   Supermarket
29  2   School
30  1   NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `GROUP BY` and `JOIN`. If there is no `NOT NULL` value for a `COD` than it should be resolved using the `OR` in `JOIN` clause.

```
 SELECT your_table.* 
 FROM your_table
 JOIN (
    SELECT COD, MAX(value) value
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY COD
 ) gt ON your_table.COD = gt.COD and (your_table.value = gt.value OR gt.value IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you may have more than one non null value for a COD this will work

```
drop table MyTable

CREATE TABLE MyTable
  (
     COD   INT,
     ID    INT,
     VALUE VARCHAR(20)
  )

INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES      (28,1, NULL),
            (28,2,'Supermarket'),
            (28,3,'School'),
            (29,1,NULL),
            (29,2,'School'),
            (29,3,NULL),
            (30,1,NULL);

WITH Dups AS
    (SELECT  COD FROM MyTable GROUP BY COD  HAVING count (*) > 1 )

    SELECT MyTable.COD,MyTable.ID,MyTable.VALUE FROM MyTable
    INNER JOIN dups ON MyTable.COD = Dups.COD
    WHERE value IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT MyTable.COD,MyTable.ID,MyTable.VALUE FROM MyTable
    LEFT JOIN dups ON MyTable.COD = Dups.COD
    WHERE dups.cod IS NULL
```